# Cuda Unsupported gpu architecture Eclipse Nsight

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda, nsight

I try to create a new project with Eclipse Nsight but when I build the project I get:

```
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_21'. 
In build setting i use Generate GPU code 2.1. The command build that Eclipse launches is:

Building file: ../src/prova.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -odir "src" -M -o "src/prova.d" "../src/prova.cu"
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/nvcc --compile -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=compute_20 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=compute_21 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  -x cu -o  "src/prova.o" "../src/prova.cu"
```

If i change `code=compute_21` with `code=compute_20` I don't have any errors. How can I change this in Eclipse Nsight?

Comment: that item should be `code=sm_21` not `code=compute_21`  It seems odd as `nsight` should be setting this automatically.  The relevant settings are in project...properties..build...cuda where you can select the code generation targets.  However, unless you've customized the project somehow, you should not get this setting.  You might want to create a new project from scratch and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

The **arch** command specifies a **virtual** architecture that will be used to generate the intermediate ptx.

The **code** command specifies the **real** architecture for which the code will be generated, either real executable code or PTX real-architecture-specific code.

`compute_21` **doesn't exist** as a virtual architecture in both of them. If you want code for the real 21 architecture use `arch=compute_20,code=sm_21`

---

So it's a configuration problem; try with the *Nsight import wizard for CUDA samples* (source: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/490324/issue-with-gencode-and-compute_21-results-in-unsupported-gpu-architecture/) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: All true, but that doesn't explain how nsight is coming up with these values.  `compute_21` is not a selectable setting within nsight.  When using nsight EE, the user is not normally typing these strings in.

Comment: I agree, modifying with some more hints

Comment: I can't find any reference to Nsight import wizard in the link you provided, furthermore, that import function is only relevant for a cuda sample, which will already have a makefile set up.  If anything, using an import wizard with a busted makefile *could* get you into the trouble that is described here.

Comment: I had this problem when i create a new project from scratch and when i import cuda samples projects with the wizard. code=compute_21 is setted by Eclipse Nsight.

Comment: @user1655904 can you try with a clean copy of it? It shouldn't be the default setting

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest  CUDA toolkit available for Fedora 19 (cuda_5.5.22_linux_64.run) and experienced the same issue.

I think the problem was that I had changed the default install location. After reinstalling the CUDA toolkit in the default location (/usr/local/cuda-5.5) and deleting the cuda-workspace directory to let Eclipse Nsight recreate it, the problem has gone.